# How to make cell fracture only fracture specific face?

Tags: modeling, add-on

Alright so I'm trying to make a cover art for a song with this heart and so i want it to have a fracture in the center and kinda have some space in between the split. The issue is that every time I try to use the Cell Fracture feature, it simulates the entire boundary of the mesh and I only want it to fracture the front part of it. I`ve tried selecting the front face in Edit Mode and a few other things but I simply can't fix this and need some help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think cell fracture is the tool you are looking for.  I would try knife project.

Comment: I couldn't understand if the add-on is not/badly working or if it works but can't help you reaching the goal. Could you post a scketch of the final result?

Comment: I just want the outside of the heart to be cracked but I want to use the simulation to make it look more natural. I:ve done this before with a dome and it worked fine.

Comment: This is what cell-fracture is supposed to do.. 
You might have more control/better results if you manually model a "crack" object and use a boolean operation to subtract it from the heart model. This is essentually what the cell fracture addon does, but using randomly generated shards.

Comment: Alright so could you walk me through how to do that so I can crack the face of the heart??